# How do I fix my true/false scoring code so that it can display score properly?

Tags: python-3.x, list, input, percentage

So the trouble I am having is the score not being properly calculated because it should have a minimum score of  0 and maximum score of 5, instead the minimum score is changed to 12, and maximum to 13. The score should be calculated if the inputted number corresponds to the answer bracket stored.

```
#This is an example of a list
questlist = ["Q1","t", "Q2", "f", "Q3", "t", "Q4","f", "Q5", "t"]

#I want to display each question individually, to be answered then moving on to the next question.


#breaks down the questlist into questions and answers.
newqlist = (questlist[::2])
anslist = (questlist[1::2])

#print (newqlist)
#print (anslist)

score = 0
for i in newqlist:
    print (i)
    answer = input("Enter 'true' for true, 'false' for false.")
    if answer == ("t"):
        count += 1
    elif answer ==("f"):
        count += 1
    else:
        print("invalid answer")
        count += 1
            
    for j in anslist:
        if answer == j:
            score +=1

print (score)

    
    
#gives back the user their score once completed
    
    # if the user gets a question correct, score will be added to a maximum of 5
    
    percentage = ((score/5)* 100)
    print ("Your score is " + str(score) + " out of 5 and " + str(percentage) + "%." )
```

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem that you're facing?

Comment: OK, so I managed to refine my code further, I'll update my code so that I may receive help with another problem I encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 things:

1. Change the loop statement to this: `for q, realAns in zip(newqlist, anslist):` This basically iterates through a list that has the question and answer paired up into tuples. So for example, the first element looks like: `("Q1", "t")`
2. Change `if answer == ("t"):` to `if answer == realAns`. This just checks whether the user's answer matches the real answer.
3. Under `if answer == realAns:`, change the `count += 1` to `score += 1`. A `score` variable doesn't exist in your code, so it would just error out.
4. Remove the `elif answer ==("f"):` statement and its corresponding `count += 1`.
5. Remove the `count += 1` under your else statement.
6. Remove this section:

```py
for j in anslist:
        if answer == j:
            score +=1
```

Since this loop runs every time your answer a question, it'll add the number of times the answer shows up in the answer list 5 times, which probably isn't what you want if you're just counting how many answers the user got right.

Your code after these changes should look something like this:

```py
#This is an example of a list
questlist = ["Q1","t", "Q2", "f", "Q3", "t", "Q4","f", "Q5", "t"]

#I want to display each question individually, to be answered then moving on to the next question.

#breaks down the questlist into questions and answers.
newqlist = (questlist[::2])
anslist = (questlist[1::2])

score = 0
for q, realAns in zip(newqlist, anslist):
    print (q)
    answer = input("Enter 'true' for true, 'false' for false.")
    if answer == realAns:
        score += 1
    else:
        print("incorrect answer")

#gives back the user their score once completed
print (score)

percentage = ((score/5)* 100)
print ("Your score is " + str(score) + " out of 5 and " + str(percentage) + "%." )
```

Comment: OK, that took care of some of my problems, now that when I made those changes, the minimum is 0 which is expected, but now the maximum became 13. How should I fix that?

Comment: @GabrielAngelos Could you provide your inputs? I ran the program and it seems to be returning a max value of 5.

Comment: The thing is, the max score with t,f,t,f,t should be 5, if I use your code, I would need to put all t for true to get a maximum score. That's why the answer should correspond with anslist. Sorry if you misunderstood my goal.

Comment: @GabrielAngelos Sorry about that! Misread the question. The updated method should work.